# How to prepare an interview with a UX researcher?

Tags: interview

When applying for a UX designer position. What and how to prepare for an interview with a UX researcher on the UX team?

Comment: Might find these helpful: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/870/how-should-i-interview-ui-and-ia-job-applicants?rq=1 , http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8458/how-do-you-best-present-yourself-in-a-ux-job-interview?rq=1 , http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/what-to-ask-when-hiring-ui-experts?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article from Whitney Hess over [the points you should be looking for when hiring a user experience designer](http://whitneyhess.com/blog/2012/09/17/how-to-evaluate-a-ux-designer-for-your-company-or-what-makes-a-great-user-experience-designer/).

Essentially you would be looking for these areas:

- Background: Process Over Portfolio
- Goal: Intel Over Instinct
- Knowledge: Principles Over Rules
- Attitude: Flexibility Over Formality
- Behavior: Assimilates Over Alienates
- Motivation: Empathy Over Ego